# AWS Immutable Server data handling strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, terraform, neo4j

I have learnt about Immutable Server pattern, and it looks very cool.
However, how do you handle data that you need to keep across different deployments, like logs or business data from your db ?

I am using Neo4j as database, running on AWS EC2 (so no out of the box database solution like RDS or DynamoDB is acceptable in answers). How do you manage for example to upgrade a server running with Neo4j from 3.3.1 to 3.3.2 with Immutable server pattern ?

Solutions with Terraform and Ansible are pretty appreciated.

Comment: You use S3, DynamoDB, RDS, etc. Suggest you get some AWS training as this kind of thing is well covered - Linux Academy provides good training.

Comment: Actually, your advice is a bit too linked to AWS. I gonna precise my question.

Comment: You're running on AWS, why on earth would AWS solutions _not_ be acceptable?!?

Comment: I did not say "ALL" AWS solutions. I said specific db solutions like RDS and DynamoDB. If for you, an acceptable solution for your customer is to migrate his current Neo4j server to RDS/DynamoDB/other AWS DB solution, this is not acceptable for me.

Comment: For example, using a separate EBS volume to store the db data, and using Terraform ability to detach it at destroy time, attach it at creation time, could be a good solution for me. But I am not expert, that's why I am asking...

Comment: You need to ask your question more carefully, more precisely, and include all relevant restrictions.

Comment: Ok. I have edited my question again.